# Pytest - Assert method is called

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytest, assert

My stripped-down code looks something along the lines of:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
import <more stuff...>

class MockClient:
    def copy_object(*args, **kwargs):
        return "dummy response"
    def <more stuff...>

@patch('boto3.Session', autospec=True)
def test_report_handler(mock_session)
    mock_session.return_value.client.return_value = MockClient
    report_handler(store="test", start_date="2018-01-10")
```

I am mocking the behavior of Boto3's Athena/S3 clients, and I want to see if copy_object() is called when report_handler() is called in my unit test.

I have read from other StackOverflow posts that this can be achieved with something along the lines of `mock_session.return_value.client.return_value.copy_object.assert_called()`, but that gives me:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'assert_called'

Any suggestions on how to check if copy_object() is called?

Comment: I am not sure you can use `unittest.mock` with `pytest`; these are two different libraries...

Comment: Your `MockClient` is not a `MagicMock`, it's just another plain class, so it doesn't count the calls. Simply make another `MagicMock` out of it, passing custom return values like `'dummy_response'` via `client.copy_object.return_value = 'dummy_response'`.